# unable to pull any docker images on redhat 7.1

Tags: curl, docker, redhat

I am stuck here - I get this error whenever I try to pull any images -

[xxxxx@xxxxx ~]$ sudo docker pull busybox

Using default tag: latest
Trying to pull repository registry.access.redhat.com/busybox ... failed
Trying to pull repository docker.io/library/busybox ... failed
Error while pulling image: Get https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/library/busybox/images: dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io: No address associated with host name

The error from what i can get at is that the server machine is not connected to internet, but it is as curl works fine, I have even downloaded packages before.
P.S - sudo docker version, sudo docker info works as expected
I have also configured cntlm and installed organization's certs
Also is there any way to know if the certs and cntlm are working correctly
Please help.

Comment: I had an error similar to this when I was working with Red Hat 7.1 there a while ago. It was the firewall on the machine where I was running the VM from, for some reason it wouldn't connect to docker at all.